# Java get Connection from DBCP Pool

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, database-connection, connection-pooling

I have a DBCP connection pool defined in my dispatcher servlet of my project.

I want to get a connection in java from the pool.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are free to get connections from the pool.What is you question?

Comment: Solved it. Attaching the solution if anyone needs.

Comment: BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
  dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:rvoracle");
dataSource.setUsername("xxxx");
dataSource.setPassword("xxxx");
dataSource.setMaxActive(100);
dataSource.setMaxWait(10000);
dataSource.setMaxIdle(10);    
  
Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();